# JQuery Add listener works from console, not from js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have function:

```
    () => {
        console.log('before');
        $('#scope_limit_toggle').change((e) => {
            console.log('from event');
        });
    }
```

The element that event is being listened is just bootstrap toggle element like this:

```
    <input id ="scope_limit_toggle" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">
```

The problem is that I can't register this event listener in any way. I have tried using:

```
    window.onload = () => {}
```

and

```
    $(function() {}
```

I have created test button that on click executes this function, but still result is the same. Everytime this first console.log() I can see printed in console but the rest seems not working (but I have no error in console). The most strange to me is that if I try to add this listener in browser console - it magically works.

So to sum up: I can execute whole function and see first console.log() printed but I can't add this event listener. However when I try to do the same from browser console - it works. Any ideas?

Comment: You can try ```$('#scope_limit_toggle').on('change', (e) => {})```

Comment: You could try using `$(document).ready(() => {});`. Also, make sure your js file is correctly imported.

Comment: @SajeebAhamed nope, problem stays the same

Comment: The ```input``` field is always there or generated dynamically?

Comment: @Nicolas you're right, the problem was import - I am using webpack but my app is nested in bigger enviroment, I think there was somehow silent conflict within jQuery, because loading jQuery as external resolved problem: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolving problem required bigger picture that I didn't mentioned in question (didn't think it was crucial) - my app is build by webpack but lives in bigger environment where jQuery has already been loaded. But I also fetched jQuery with npm to my webpack build and the conflict arised (although not resulted in any errors during build or using app).

What was solution? jQuery has been loaded so just make use of it in webpack as mentioned here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/.

Now all works perfectly.